# discontinuity of functions

Tags: calculus, continuity

got stuck on the next question,

Find the points of discontinuity of the function if they exist:

$f(x)={\begin{cases}\sin x&{\mbox{ for }}x \in\mathbb {Q} \\0&{\mbox{ for }}x\notin\mathbb{Q} \\\end{cases}}$

I would really appreciate a hint

Comment: Use the epsilon delta definition.  To prove discontinuous let $\epsilon = |\sin x| \ne 0$ on on the $x$ that are not so that $\sin x= 0$.  For $x$s where $\sin x = 0$ try to prove continuous.  (It's not enough to state the limits are equal to zero.  You must prove that.)

Answer (score 1):

If $q\ne0$ is rational, then take a sequence $(r_n)$ of irrationals converging to $q$. Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(r_n)=0\ne f(q)=\sin q
$$
Thus $f$ is continuous at no rational point $q\ne0$.

Consider an irrational number $r$ and let $(q_n)$ be a sequence of rationals converging to $r$. Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(q_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin q_n=\sin r
$$
by continuity of the sine. In order that the function is continuous at $r$, you need $\sin r=f(r)=0$, that is, $r=k\pi$ for some integer $k\ne0$.

Therefore the function is not continuous at all irrational points not equal to $k\pi$, $k\ne0$ integer.

It remains to investigate whether the function *is* continuous at points of the form $k\pi$ ($k$ integer). Can you prove it?

Comment: "$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(r_n)=0\ne f(q)=\sin q$   What if $q = 0$? "Thus f is continuous at no rational point" What if $q = 0$?

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I'll fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Its continuous at those points $x$ such that $\sin x=0$ and only at those points.

Comment: isn't it also discontinuous? After all between any two rational numbers there are infinite rational numbers and therefore if we examine the limit on the right and the left we will get two different numbers or not?

Comment: No, we will not. Both limits will be $0$.

Comment: i have posted an answer, would appreciate your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)={\begin{cases}\sin x&{\mbox{ for }}x \in\mathbb {Q} \\0&{\mbox{ for }}x\notin\mathbb{Q} \\\end{cases}}$

we will choose $x_0 \notin \mathbb {Q}$ so that $\sin(x_0)=0$

so by definition $f(x_0) = 0$

${\displaystyle \lim _{x\to x_{0}}f(x)={\displaystyle \lim _{x\to x_{0}}\sin(x)= 0 = f(x_0)}}$

so for any ${\displaystyle x \not= \pi k }$ the function is discontinuous

Comment: SInce $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$, how do you deduce that $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$? Shouldn't you have deduced that it is continuous there?

Comment: yes i am saying that, im saying that for each x $\not=\pi k$ the function is discontinuous

Comment: But didn't you say that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$ then? And doesn't that mean that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$?

Comment: "yes i am saying that, im saying that for each x ≠πk the function is discontinuous"  Why?  If $g$ is continuous at $x=0$, does that mean $g$ is *not* continuous when $x\ne 0$?  Why should $f$ being continuous when $x = \pi k$ mean that $x$ is *not* continuous at $x \ne \pi k$.  What if it turns out that $f$ is continuous at $x = k \pi$ and it is also continuous at $x =\sqrt 2$.  You have proven it *isn't* continuous at $x=\sqrt{x}$.